How to bypass press and hold captcha using python and selenium?
I am using Selenium and Python to scrape data from the iHerb website. However, I am encountering a captcha that is preventing me from successfully extracting the desired information. How can I overcome this captcha challenge and proceed with the scraping process?
I attempted to use Selenium actions to press and hold an element, but it was unsuccessful because it is located within a shadow root containing an iframe.
I tried the code
`
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#px-captcha')
            action = ActionChains(driver)
            action.click_and_hold(element)
            action.perform()
            time.sleep(10)
            action.release(element)
            action.perform()
            time.sleep(0.2)
            action.release(element)

